# Change the colour of WinJS.UI.BackButton (Win 8.1 back button)

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm getting started with Windows 8 App development using WinJS. I'm using the Light UI theme but I have set up a darker area on the left of the page (where the black back button is) and the issue is: you can't see the button.

I've trawled through the MSDN pages and the most I could find is how to style a button which doesn't actually explain how to change the colour of an actual asset.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj835822.aspx

I've also tried adding: win-ui-light and win-ui-dark classes to the button with no success.

I wondered if someone could point me in the right direction?

Many thanks for your time

Chris

Comment: Give the button an `id` and assign it new back and fore colors via CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the DOM Explorer to find the buttons default values and overwrite them. It was the child element that needed to be overwritten: .win-back

Comment: Yep, using the DOM explorer is a great way to find the style classes that you need to work with. I also have better documentation for styling in Chapter 5 of my free ebook, Programming Windows Store Apps in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, Second Edition. Preview is on http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2. You might also want to include ".win-navigation-backbutton:hover .win-back" and also :active variants to control the other states as well. (It's usually helpful to also look in the WinJS stylesheets for the selectors that set the defaults.)

Comment: That's awesome advice and thanks for the free eBook! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to delete the link tag that contain UI css by default and add it to document head , Dynamically.see below code :

```
var uistyle;

 // call when your app load or resume.
function onappopen(){           
uistyle = document.createElement('link');
uistyle.href = "//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css";
uistyle.rel = "stylesheet";
uistyle.id = "UIstyle";
document.head.appendChild(uistyle);}

// call when you want to change UI Style.
function UIstyle(UIbool){      
if(UIbool=='light'){ uistyle.href = "//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-light.css";}
else {uistyle.href = "//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css";}}
```

Like: UIstyle('light'); for light UI in Windows 8 or "UIstyle()" for dark;